# Android Emulator Crashes Claiming "Null Notification"

Tags: android, android-notifications

I'm running into a bug in the android code described here:

http://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=9840

However I'm extremely confused by what they are saying for example:

> I also sent a NULL notification by mistake, and crashed the system
>   process. My code was:
>
> ```
>         int icon = R.drawable.notification_icon;
>         CharSequence tickerText = "Filter Active";
>         long when = System.currentTimeMillis();
>
>         Notification n = new Notification(icon, tickerText, when);
>         startForeground(startId, n);
> ```
>
> from a service.

I don't understand why he's saying that he's sending a null notification when n is clearly being instantiated and passed to the startForeground service method. This is almost exactly what my code looks like and I can't find any explanation as to why it's wrong or what is the proper way.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found it.

I agree with the sentiments expressed here. Completely unacceptable on all counts. Lack of documentation, ridiculous default behavior and a blatent design flaw which crashes the entire OS.

http://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=930

Essentially the `setLatestEventInfo` method *must* be called for the notification to be valid.

Comment: I find the [documentation](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/notifiers/notifications.html) satisfactory if not wonderful. Also, it doesn't make a whole lot of sense to have a notification without a title/text. I do agree though that you shouldn't be able to crash a system service like that. I would guess it's just been a lower priority bug because it's fairly hard to do without noticing so I doubt it's made it into too many released apps.

Comment: Oh, also I think they recognized that the API isn't so wonderful and so added a [Builder](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Notification.Builder.html) to clean it up. Only API 11 though unfortunately.

Comment: I don't think many people look at document examples and expect the entire piece of code to be written exactly that way otherwise horrible things will happen. Especially if the piece of code they leave out seems to be optional and especially if no graceful Runtime Error is presented for doing so.